# LinkButton OnCommand Function Only Fires on First Click if OnClientClick="return false"

Tags: c#, asp.net

So I have a linkButton that I don't want the page to refresh when clicked so I have OnClientClick="return false;". This prevents the page from refreshing however, the function being called from the OnCommand field only fires the first time it is clicked. In order to get it to fire again, I need to refresh the page.

How can I make the OnCommand function fire every time it is clicked while keeping OnClientClick="return false;" so the page isn't refreshed each time?

```
<asp:LinkButton CssClass="btn pauseButton" ID="pauseSubBtn" runat="server" OnCommand="populatePauseModal" CommandArgument="<%# Item.FirstName %>" OnClientClick="return false;">Pause</asp:LinkButton>
```

This link button is inside of a list view, which is inside of an update panel. I tried setting a AsyncPostBackTrigger but it can't find the link button because it's inside the list view.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that. To process an `OnCommand` you will need a PostBack (page refresh). You could use `UpdatePanel` to make it look like there is no page refresh. But it seems you are already using it but are having trouble adding the trigger.

You can add a trigger to the LinkButton programatically

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (ListViewDataItem item in ListView1.Items)
    {
        LinkButton lb = item.FindControl("pauseSubBtn") as LinkButton;
        ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(lb);
    }
}
```